# Prove by contradiction that for a transitive relation $R$ on $A$, $R^2$ is also transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Prove by contradiction that for a transitive relation $R$ on $A$, $R^2$ is also transitive.

In order for a relation to be transitive it must satisfy
$$aRc \wedge bRc \rightarrow aRc$$
for all $a,b,c \in A$.

Comment: Here, $R^2=R\circ R = \{(x,z)\mid\exists y\, xRyRz\}$?

Comment: By $R^2$ do you mean the relation on $A \times A$ given by $(a,b) R^2 (c,d)$ iff $a R c$ and $b R d$?

Comment: @Stefan Funny, neither of us is sure, and both guesses are plausible.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried?

Comment: It's really part of the problem statement that you have to prove this *by contradiction*? Frankly, that seems silly/pointless, as you can just prove it outright, then convert your proof into one by contradiction by assuming $\neg$ [what you want to prove], proving what you want to prove (without using the negated statement at all), and concluding that what you want to prove is true. $(\neg p\to p)\to p$ is a tautology.

Comment: @CameronBuie I'm mostly lost on just reading the problem correctly, would it be safe to assume $R^2$ is R o R?

Comment: @ OP You'd know better than any of us what $R^2$ is supposed to mean! It must be defined *somewhere*, in material you have but we don't. I'd say, it probably means $R\circ R$. But if it means the relation that @Stefan mentions, that's transitive too, if $R$ is. Prove both! they're easy.

Comment: @BrianO I wish I could tell you guys more, but "Prove by contradiction that for a transitive relation $R$ on $A$, $R^2$ is also transitive." is the whole question. The $R^2$ was throwing me off so I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: I'd say, go with $R\circ R$, it's more likely.

Comment: Their interpretation is likely the correct one. Still, you should check your notes/text/materials to be sure.

Comment: Do you  have a typo? $aRc \wedge bRc \rightarrow aRc$ is certainly true, regardless of what $R$ is, but what about $aRb \wedge bRc \rightarrow aRc$?

Answer (score 1):

Proving this by contradiction seems weird, but here goes: Assume to the contrary that $R$ is transitive, but $R^2$ is not transitive.

Since $R^2$ is not transitive, there exists $x,y,z\in A$, such that $(x,y)\in R^2$, $(y,z)\in R^2$, but $(x,z)\not\in R^2$.

By definition of $R^2$ there exists $u_1,u_2\in A$, such that $(x,u_1)\in R$, $(u_1,y)\in R$, $(y,u_2)\in R$, and $(u_2,z)\in R$. Since $R$ is transitive, we obtain also that $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$.

By definition of $R^2$, this implies $(x,z)\in R^2$, which contradicts $(x,z)\not\in R^2$.